# How to Update Icon for Office 365 Mail Add-in

Tags: add-in, office365, outlook-addin, napa

I'm developing an Office 365 Mail Add-in in Napa and want to set the app icon. There is a manifest XML file that can include an IconUrl element, but the Napa platform doesn't provide an avenue for uploading my manifest.

Is there a way to set the icon using Napa? If not, what can I use to deploy a version of my add-in to my test account with the updated manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend that if you are ready to custom your manifest, you should consider using [Visual Studio 2015 Community with Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx). Napa is a lightweight playground for exploring and trying out the Office Add-ins quickly and I think you'll find that you have a lot more power in VS.

If you are using a mac, download your project from Napa and you can use any preferred development environment (instructions on [how to debug with a text editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161148.aspx)).

Thanks for asking and please feel free to reach out again if you have any more questions!

Nicole, Program Manager for Microsoft Office Development Tools

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would reference the icon image in the manifest just as you would reference image files in .html pages in your solution.  For example, store the icon in the Contents or Images folder and reference it using virtual paths. It has to be stored on the web server whether your .html, .js and .css files are located.

Note that the only place you really upload your manifest is within the Addin management pages within your Mailbox or via the Exchange Admin Center pages.